# Braintree payment test automation using java - how to generate the nonce from a Java client?

Tags: java, automated-tests, braintree, braintree-sandbox

Our product uses Braintree as the payment gateway, and I'm currently trying to automate the payment workflow. The tests I'm writing are TestNG based java tests.

[image]

The diagram describes how payment goes through Braintree. Here are the steps:

- (1/2) The client asks your server for auth nonce.
- (3) The client uses
  the nonce from #1/2 along with credit card information to request for payment nonce from Braintree.
- (4/5) The client uses payment nonce to
  complete the payment using the application server.

The client SDKs provided by Braintree (which helps you generate nonce at #3) are:

1. JS
2. Android
3. IOS

My challenge is, in my case, the client is a test written in java, and Braintree does not have a java client SDK

At first glance, it seems I can use the Android SDK to get this done but looks like the entire workflow is very tightly coupled with BraintreeFragment. I'm afraid I'll go down a rabbit hole without any conclusion if I proceed this way.

Have anyone else tried doing this and have a way to achieve this? Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: The picture may be misleading. The nonce is what the Braintree server _returns_ to you at step 3, but it's not clear what you are supposed to send.  Is it the token you generated earlier? Check the Braintree documentation.

Comment: Yes, I'm supposed to send the token generated in step 1 along with my credit / debit card details. That will give me the nonce (or another token for repeated payment) which I'll use to make the payment.

Comment: The token I get from my server helps the client to set the identity of the merchant (to whom I'm going to pay).

Comment: So what is the question? You say _"I'm not sure how to generate the nonce at step 3"_, but it is not up to you to generate the nonce? Please clarify the question.

Comment: The diagram describes how payment goes through braintree. Here are the steps:        1. As a client ask your server for auth nonce. 2. Client uses the nonce from #1 along with credit card information to request for payment nonce from Braintree. 3. Client uses payment nonce to complete the payment using application server.

Comment: My challenge is, in my case the client is a test written in java, and Braintree does not have a java client SDK

Comment: I modified the description to add more details

Comment: @smaikap : 2022 : there is a Java SDK for braintree api . For future readers : see https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/reference/request/payment-method-nonce/create/java